# Diamond inheritance and the MRO

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

I'm a newbie for MRO and having problem figuring out the logic for these outputs.

#### Case 1:

```
class A(object):
  def save(self):
      print "A"

class B(A):
    def save(self):
        print "B"
        super(B, self).save()

class C(A):
  def save(self):
      print "C"
      super(C, self).save()


class D(C, B):
    def save(self):
        print "D"
        super(D,self).save()

D().save()
```

Output:

```
D
C
B
A
```

My question here is how `super(C)` is calling `B.save()`.

As per MRO: `super(C, self)` is not about the "base class of `C`", but about the next class in the MRO list of `C`. But there is no `B` in MRO list of `C`.

#### Case 2:

```
class A(object):
  def save(self):
      print "A"

class B(A):
    def save(self):
        print "B"
        super(B, self).save()

class C(A):
  def save(self):
      print "C"
      # removed super call here

class D(C, B):
    def save(self):
        print "D"
        super(D,self).save()

D().save()
```

Output:

```
D
C
```

#### Case 3:

```
class A(object):
  def save(self):
      print "A"

class B(object):
    #inherits object now instead of A
    def save(self):
        print "B"
        super(B, self).save()

class C(A):
  def save(self):
      print "C"
      super(C, self).save()

class D(C, B):
    def save(self):
        print "D"
        super(D,self).save()

D().save()
```

Output:

```
D
C
A
```

#### Question

How is the MRO affected if `B` is not inheriting from `A`, but `object` directly?

Can someone explain the reason behind this?

Comment: Hope this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165923/mro-with-multiple-inheritance-in-python?rq=1

Comment: According to this link: D.mro() is C B A object. save() is found in class C but yet again it is going to B.save() which is not in C.mro(). That's the point which is confusing me at the very first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to tackle these questions, you need to, first, understand how do **MRO** and **super()** work.

**MRO** [Python Document - MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)
In Python, MRO is based on C3 linearization. (There are many examples in wiki and python documents)

**super()** (check out Python Document - super())
According to the Python Document, it says..

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent **or** sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class. The search order is same as that used by getattr() except that the type itself is skipped.

Therefore, **super()** will search based on **MRO** (`classobject.__mro__`) and it will be satisfied by either parent class or sibling class of type.

Back to your cases,
**Case 1**
`D.__mro__ = (D, C, B, A, object)`
Thus, the output will be `D C B A`

**Case 2**
The MRO of D is as the same as D in case 1. (`(D, C, B, A, object)`)
However, **super()** will stop, or be satisfied, at **C** because `save()` in class C does not have a super function call implemented.

**Case 3**
The MRO of D is equal to `(D, C, A, B, object)`. Therefore, when **super()** reached save() function in class A, it would consider satisfied. That's the reason why save function in B had never been called.

Moreover, if you switch the inheritance sequence of D from C, B to B, C. (`class D(C, B)` to `class D(B, C)`). Then, when you call `D().save()`, the output will be **D B** because `D.__mro__ = (D, B, C, A, object)` and super() will be satisfied at class B.

Furthermore, from my understanding, **super()** is not a function that forces child class object to call **all** override functions in parent classes. If you want to force your class to call all override functions in its parent classes. You could try to do something like:

```
class Base(object):
    def method(self):
        print('Base-method')

class Parent(object):
    def method(self):
        print('Parent-method')

class Child(Parent):
    def method(self):
        print('Child-method')
        super(Child, self).method()

class GrandChild(Child, Base):
    def method(self):
        print('GrandChild-method')
        for base in GrandChild.__bases__:
            base.method(self)
        #super(GrandChild, self).method()
```

Then, when you call `GrandChild().method(), the output will be:

```
GrandChild-method
Child-method
Parent-method
Base-method
```

Note:
`GrandChild.__bases__` contains only class Child and class Base

PS.
By saying **satisfied** above, I meant there is no more super() calls.